# The code on this page disabled back and forward caching in Internet Explorer angular 2

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, caching

My Angular application (site) is loaded on Edge and chrome but not loading on Internet Explorer. It shows following error :
The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.

Comment: Please check your code, whether you disable the cache? If you disabled it, please try to enable it. If you didn't set it, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The file is too long. It is not allowing to post here. Please have a look at this screenshot. 
https://prnt.sc/pda1li

Comment: I searched some resource about the error, it seems that the issue might be related to the http request cache setting, please check the related code in your application. Besides, you could also post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to uncomment the polyfills for IE in polyfills.ts file. Without polyfills, Angular may not work in IE. They are included in any Angular project creatd by Angular CLI by default but commented.

Comment: Can you paste here contents of your polyfill? Also, clear cache in browser and restart Angular CLI (do ng serve again) to ensure the changes reflect.

Comment: File is too long to put here. Please have a look at the screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/pda1li

Comment: These three important polyfills are missing: import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/array';

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have put these three polyfills but still its not working.

Comment: That's unfortunate. May be you can post some more details. The code causing the error and the exact error trace.